# How to fix "Declaration, final or effectively final variable expected" in a PreparedStatement.setString

Tags: java, sql, intellij-idea

The problem is that I am trying to set a wild card in a PreparedStatement but the setString statement is giving me the error above.

I have tried changing it to a setObeject statement with multiple different types like Types.VARCHAR. I have tried declaring the PreparedStatement in different places, and I have tried declaring 'name' in the method and in the class.

```
public String getTemplateText(String name) {
    try (
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT templateText FROM TEMPLATE WHERE " +
                    "templateTag = ?");
            stmt.setString(1 , name); // this is the line that has the problem!
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()
    ) {
        System.out.println("Set Text...");
        String tempText = rs.getString("templateText");
        return tempText;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

```
/* this is the SQL code for the table that I am trying to query */
CREATE TABLE TEMPLATE
(
    templateID      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
  , templateText    TEXT
  , templateTag     CHAR(25)
);
```

Comment: You can't put arbitrary statements inside the `()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't set the `stmt` parameter in your `try-with-resources` (because binding the parameter is `void` and not *closable*). Instead, you can nest a second `try-with-resources` after you bind the parameter. Like,

```
public String getTemplateText(String name) {
    try (Connection conn = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT templateText FROM TEMPLATE WHERE " + 
                    "templateTag = ?")) {
        stmt.setString(1, name);
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            System.out.println("Set Text...");
            String tempText = rs.getString("templateText");
            return tempText;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: completely off topic but in terms of readability: it's 100% correct and I hate it. The only way of cleaning this up I can think of is omitting the nested method body and simply returning the `#getString` directly (without abstracting things to new methods / a library). And that's it for my venting tonight.